# Central SSE listener in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, server-sent-events

I'm working on an application with a couple of controllers that listen to Server-Sent events. Currently, these controllers incorporate a service that enables them to connect to a specific URL that sends out these events, the parameters (and permissions) dictate what messages are in fact being sent.

At this point, every logged in user is connected to this URL multiple times with different parameters, because each controller has their own interests. I know which messages are relevant to the current session, so I would like to reduce the number of connections to just one. I figured I could broadcast to the `$rootScope`, but what now? Should I create a "dummy" controller that broadcasts on the `$rootScope` or is there a better way? Should this maybe go into a `run` block?

Comment: instead of binding each to event, have callback assign data to variable in service and each controller binds to that variable

Comment: Would this be something like a "global" variable? The thing is that the events trigger various actions, like table reloads.

Comment: can broadcast events throughout angular , see docs